# How would I output this multiplication table with an if statement?

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, multiplication, n-dimensional

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char response = 'y';
    while (response == 'y')
        do
        {
        const int myarray = 144;
        int thearray[myarray];
        for (int m = 0; m < 12; m++)
        {
            cout << m + 1 << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int rown = 1; rown < 11; rown++)
            for (int n = 0; n < 12; n++)
            {
                thearray[(rown * 12) + n] = thearray[n] * (rown + 1);
            }
        if ()
    cout << "Would you like to run the program again? \n"
        << "Enter y for yes or n for no: ";
    cin >> response;
} while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y');
return 0;
}
```

The point of this code is to use a 1 dimensional array to create a multiplication table. I believe that I have everything coded right but the other part of this assignment is to output the table using an if statement and I'm not entirely sure how. Can someone give me some guidance please?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. What do you mean using an `if statement` ? can you give us a little more detail of what the output should look like?

Comment: The output is supposed to look like an actual multiplication table. Using setw.

Comment: like it should be 12 rows and 12 columns with the 144 digits in a multiplication

Comment: Is this code C++?  Please edit in a language tag into your question.

Comment: `if ()` looks a little ... broken.... If ... what?

Comment: Yes this is C++. The if statement was what I was going to use to create the output but it wasn't working out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the function of C, but i presume it would work like this (thought process / logic only, not actual code)

```
nums = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
output space for left display column of numbers
foreach (nums as header) { // this hopefully builds the top of the table
  output header; // column header
}
for each (nums as row) { // this will go through 1,2,3,4,5 
  if (nums === multiplier) output left row label // i.e "1 | "
  for each (nums as col) {       
    output (row * col) // multiply row * col and display it
  }
}
```

No If statement required ... hope that helps.
sorry if the code isn't complete, i dont program in c much.

**EDIT:**

For the sake of sanity I wrote something up that seems to work. Always good to learn new languages :) .... let me know what you think.

```
https://ideone.com/Id9Ax9
```

This is the code I came up with that worked for me

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
// Define variables
    int nums [5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    // set default values
    string headerRow = "    ";
    string rowLabel = "";
    string currentRow = "";
    string currentVal = "";
    // start the process
    int maxArray = (sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]));
    for (int i=1; i<=maxArray; i++) { headerRow = headerRow + to_string(i) + "  "; }
    cout << headerRow + "\n"; // Display header row
    cout << "    ---------------\n";
    for (int r=1; r<=maxArray; r++) { // this will cycle through rows 1,2,3,4,5 
        currentRow = "";
        for (int c=1; c<=maxArray; c++) {// this will cycle through columns 1,2,3,4,5 
            if (r == c) {
                rowLabel = to_string(r) + std::string(" | "); 
            }
            currentVal = to_string(c * r) + "  "; // multiply row * col and display it
            currentRow = currentRow + currentVal;
        }    
        cout << rowLabel + currentRow + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Though looking at the original question .. assignment? did I just do your homework for you?

Comment: More or less. That actually didn't work for me. Thank you for that suggestion though.

Comment: yesh .. it is definitely not functional code .. you'd have to rewrite it with the actual commands in c++ ... but I believe the ideas is solid.

Comment: Oh no let me rephrase that. I'm working with what you've given me and it hasn't worked as of yet.

Comment: I don't know c++, but I did run through and make a test version of this online (with a little help from google regarding variable types in c++). See my notes above for the example that is working.

Comment: no problem .. a bit of a learning curve as I'm used to PHP ... but the idea worked out and I was able to take my original thoughts and make something in C++ that worked :)